# Totals on a report summary

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access Report. In the footer section of my report I have a list of different totals. I am looking to create these totals based on a time criteron. For example:

Im looking for a count of the included records. I need to determine a count based on either current- 3 months, 4-6 months, 7-12 Months and 13+ Months.

I have created a DateDiff() expression to determine the amount of months. I have created another expression to assign a letter based on what group the result would belong to. For example:

```
A = Current - 3months
B = 4-6 Months
C = 7-12 Months
D = 13+ Months
```

How could I use the assigned letter as a count on my report? Could I make a statement in my control source for my display text box to accomplish this?

I'm not sure where to go next...

Comment: Can you put the results of your count query in your report?

Answer (score 0):

In the reports On_Open event write some VBA to store the values from your DateDiff into several different String Variables, and then if your footer is a simple text box just update the values e.g.

```
txtFooter = "3Mnths - " & str3Mnths & " - 4/6Mnths - " & str46Mnths
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Not sure thats quite what I'm looking for. Let me explain further.

I need to find a count by the different dates. Basically, if the record is less than 3 months, I have assigned an "A" to that record. If the record is between 4-6 Months, I have assigned a "B" to that record. I need to figure out a count of each letter. How many records in the query are "A" and seperate counts by each letter "B" "C" ect.

Comment: Ah, I see; sorry about that, can you not add a sub query onto the report to show those values?

Comment: I haven't consider a subquery approach. I'm not quite sure how to use them. For further identification: The field that calculates which letter to assign based on the month is called [SoldDateDiff]. On my report I have several text boxes in the footer to calculate different totals of the executed query. Basically I need to do something like this: Count([SoldDateDiff] WHERE [SoldDateDiff] = "A") another text box will do: Count([SoldDateDiff] WHERE [SoldDateDiff] = "B") Hope that helps. As always, thanks for yours!

Comment: I can acheive the desired result from the DCount function.
    =DCount("[SoldDateDiffGrp]","[qrySearch]","[SoldDateDiffGrp]='C'")
Unless you can think of a better approach. I know its not good practice to use the domain functions frequently.

Comment: To be honest, I think that solution will be fine in this case, if your query was slow to execute then I would advise against it, but if the report is quick to load then this is the simpliest solution : )